# Can an Objective-C implementation be defined in a header file and also be imported by multiple source files?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, objective-c-runtime

I am aware this is not standard or conventional, please read on. I have a header file that defines the interface and implementation of an Objective-C class.

**Person.h**

```
#ifndef Person_h
#define Person_h

@interface Person : NSObject
-(void)speak;
@end

@implementation Person
-(void)speak
{
    // Say something
}
@end

#endif /* Person_h */
```

I also have two source files that both include the header file.

**Main.mm**

```
@import Foundation;
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

**Test.mm**

```
@import Foundation;
#import "Person.h"
```

When the project is built, I get duplicate symbol errors.

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_Person' in:
        /Debug/TestBox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
        /Debug/TestBox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.o
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_Person' in:
        /Debug/TestBox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
        /Debug/TestBox.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I want to be able to include the same header file in multiple source files. In C++, I can inline the implementation into the header file like this:

```
#ifndef Person_h
#define Person_h

class Person
{
public:
    void speak()
    {
        // Say something
    }
};

#endif /* Person_h */
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to do that with Objective-C. I'm using Objective-C so I can subclass events from NSWindowDelegate and NSResponder.

I tried searching for solutions. Most of them said to separate the implementation into a source file, but that would break the single-header architecture. One suggestion is to use the [Objective-C runtime library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime) and create my classes at runtime. This appears to give me the results I'm looking for, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Is there some way to implement an Objective-C class in a header file so it can be included by multiple source files? Or is dynamically creating the classes at runtime my best option?

---

**Update**

I am looking for a solution that avoids using a .m or .mm file to write the Objective-C implementation. Even if doing so is not the conventional way to do it. The single-header file is required by the architecture of the project I am working on. The project is cross-platform, and the single-header design isn't an issue in C++ on Windows and Linux. Adding a source file to define Objective-C objects would break the existing architecture.

Comment: The standard method is to use a .m file for implementation and restrict the .h contents to public declarations.  What do you see as an advantage by dumping everything into the header?

Comment: No. You never want to put an implementation in a header file.

Comment: @PhillipMillis, the project I am working on is a collection of cross-platform libraries. The single-header design makes it easy to manage the distribution of the project.  It saves us time not compiling different configurations of dll's and lib's for different operating systems. 

It also makes it easy for the end-user to add to their project. We want to make it as simple as possible to get started using our libraries. With the single-header, all a developer needs to do is include the one file, and they are ready to use it.

Comment: @Rob, that is the consensus I've read so far about header-only files. However, if there is a way to do it in Objective-C, we would like to try it. We want to avoid changing our current architecture because it already works well in C++ on Windows and Linux.

Comment: So, the "libraries" you distribute have no (system-specific) binary components?

Comment: Some of our libraries do make use of platform-specific binaries. In those cases, we provide instructions on how to install them. The end-user can add #defines before they include the single-header to enable or disable different libraries. This way, if they don't need a specific library, it won't get compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Thats not purpose of header file. In header file you will define properties and methods which you want to make available where needed.
Implementation always lies within .m file in case of Objective C.

Comment: I understand it may not be the purpose of a header file. However, it is a possible way to write implementation in C++ by inlining. My question is asking if it is possible in Objective-C? Or is there another solution that also avoids using .m or .mm files?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the different purposes of header (.h) and module (.m) files:

The correct usage is this:

A **Header file** just *declares* the types and what they are composed of. It is like saying to the compiler: Look, somewhere is a class named `Person`, and you can call `speak` on it. It does *not* tell the compiler the internals of the `speak` function, it just announces that this type exists *somewhere*.
This is called a *type declaration*.

When the compiler translates the `Main.mm` file, it creates a call to a yet-unknown, external function `speak`. It does the same for `Test.mm`.

Then, after compilation of your code, the *linker* runs to resolve all the unknown addresses, e.g. it checks if there is one and *exactly* one definition of a class `Person`with a function `speak`. If there is no such definition, you get an *unresolved symbol* error. If there are multiple definitions, you get your *duplicate symbol* error.

Therefore, you need to create a **Module file** to *define* all your classes - exactly once. In your case you need a file `Person.m`, which contains the `@implementation` of the class (and functions).

Types can be declared multiple times, but may only be defined once.

**What you did wrong:** When you put your type definition into the header file, the compiler creates two implementations of your class (when translating `Main.mm` and the other when translating `Test.mm`), which then confuses the linker, because the linker expects exactly one.

---

You *can* have a central header file which aggregates all types and sub-includes, but you need one (or more) separate module files - and you must not include them, because the linker resolves the references for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand the different purposes header and module files. However, this can be circumvented in C++ by implicitly inlining the class implementation. When a class is inlined in a header file, more than one definition is possible in different translation units. Is it possible to inline a class in Objective-C?

Comment: No, there is no such thing as an "inline" class, neither in ObjC nor in C++. C++ has something like inline (member) functions which work as you described. In ObjC you can have (global) inline (or NS_INLINE) functions, but not member functions, because they are always dynamically dispatched and never ever inlined (except some special cases for retain/release etc.)

Comment: Good to know, I'll stop pursuing that kind of solution then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Sure thing, of course you can ... I've removed the previous failed attempt to remove clutter.

```
// main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"
#import "C.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        [[A alloc] init];
        [[B alloc] init];
        [[C alloc] init];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
// A.h, repeat for B.h and C.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject

@end
```

```
// A.m
// B.m and C.m are quite similar
// BUT drop the line below from B and C
#define ZIMP

#import "A.h"
#import "Header.h"

@implementation A

- ( id ) init
{
    self = super.init;

    [[[Z alloc] init] msg:@"A"];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Now for the grand finale

```
// Header.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Z : NSObject

- ( void ) msg:( NSString * ) src;

@end

#ifdef ZIMP

@implementation Z

- ( void ) msg:( NSString * ) src
{
    NSLog( @"%@ says hi", src );
}

@end

#endif
```

The proof of the pudding ... here is the output

```
2020-07-15 07:29:52.134413+0200 HdrImp[26901:700649] Hello, World!
2020-07-15 07:29:52.135121+0200 HdrImp[26901:700649] A says hi
2020-07-15 07:29:52.135297+0200 HdrImp[26901:700649] B says hi
2020-07-15 07:29:52.135389+0200 HdrImp[26901:700649] C says hi
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The trick is of course to get the compiler to see the implementation only once, even though the header file is included several times. This is accomplished with nothing but a single `#define`.

Now we can tell the Swift guys that Objective-C can be done with just a single source file.

**UPDATE**

This works because I know precisely which files will be included and I can set the guard in one of them. If you do not know beforehand which of the files will be part of the compile you have a problem but you can solve that with more defines and by some code in your `make` file where you 'know' which of the files will be included and can take action based on that.

Comment: It would be nice if that's all it took. Changing @import to #import or #include makes no difference in this example. Unfortunately, moving the header guards doesn't work because Main.mm and Test.mm get compiled into separate translation units. When Main.mm defines Person_imp, Test.mm won't know that, so Test.mm also defines Person_imp. The compiler is seeing the code only once, once per source file.

Comment: Not sure this is worth exploring but maybe if you can generate one huge include file or one huge preprocessed file that is compiled once but it feels terribly hacky and as if it is going downhill from where we are now ... so I think maybe you need to rework this. Why not compile to some library and then link against it? Wouldn't that fit with your architecture?

Comment: Ah - just thought of something. Why not guard the implementation with say X and then define X only in one of the mm files? That way you can 'see' it only once?

Comment: ... and based on that thought, see the edit to my answer!

Comment: Honestly, this is not the way you should program in any C family language. Your result is that class Z will be implemented in when compiling A.m, and will be part of A.m. What if someone just needs B, C and Z but not A?

Comment: Of course not, I am not proposing that this is good practice, neither is the OP. Read the first sentence of OP again. This is a very specific problem and I provided a very specific solution that works specifically for this.

Comment: I do not entirely agree with you - C was specifically designed to be portable and that is why you have #define and so on and why you can actually do things like this. In order to be portable you would sometimes do things like ```#define float double``` e.g. which may give you a heart attack but which also made C and family incredibly portable.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately those C libraries are completely unreadable. But including the implementation in each file and then using #define to undo this and only let it be visible by one file is weired. The utmost I would agree to would be one single .m file that only includes the other .m file (or not, by #define).

Comment: What you describe is OP's problem and solution I provided. The weird problem requires a weird solution. Do not criticise it because it is weird and yes it is not standard practice but it is nice that you have this much control over the compiler which is what #define gives you. This amount of control leads to abuses like this, but it is actually a good thing as it proofs that we have a lot of control over the compiler.

Comment: ... even Objective-C started out as a preprocessor file, a good use of this power ...

Comment: @ahzeee this works because I know precisely which files will be included and I can set the guard in one of them. If you do not know beforehand which of the files will be part of the compile you have a problem but you can solve that with more defines and by some code in your ```make``` file where you 'know' which of the files will be included and can take action based on that. I'm moving this into the solution as it is probably important to note ...

Comment: @skaak, very interesting, it took me a while to wrap my head around it, but I think I understand what you're doing now. However, I can't use this. You are using a .m file for the implementation of each interface, which is not allowed in the header-only architecture I'm working on. I am restricted to having one header file that contains the interface, as well as the implementation. My goal is to give that one header file the ability to be included by multiple source files without causing duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: I also can't use this because it would only work with a finite number of source files. While it might be possible to use the #define's to get around duplicate symbols in each translation unit, this would depend on how many translation units the preprocessor code is written for. With our current C++ solution on Windows and Linux, we can support a presumably infinite number of source files that include the header by inlining the class implementation. I'm looking for an equivalent to that. Nonetheless, thank you for your answers so far.

Comment: Ok - that is a pity. I can't help but think the solution is still here somewhere eg include the header in your main.c and put the #define there. So the implementation is only compiled when you (must) compile main and all the other sources don't see the implementation. But I also lack knowledge of your particular problem. Do you even have a main? What do you mean with source file? .c? .m? .h? Also, don't try to solve this with inlining, you need some approach like this here otherwise it gets quite hacky if at all possible.

Comment: Just to clarify my suggestion. If you have a main.c then put the #define there and also include the header with guarded implementation there. This means the implementation gets compiled together with main. Then in all the other source files you can just include the header and they see the interface but not the implementation.

Comment: The consensus I've gotten so far suggests inlining the implementation is impossible with Objective-C. I'm moving on from that idea. By "source file" I mean any file that becomes an object file like .cpp, .m, and .mm.

Comment: The project I'm working on is a collection of different libraries that get combined and distributed in a single header file. We don't have a main. The end-user is the one who writes the main in their project and includes our header file. In the example code I provided, Main.mm and Test.mm is one way the user might decide to use our header file, Person.h. We can support this on other operating systems but not Mac. We want to match our project's capabilities across each operating system.

Comment: Ok - when we are done here we'll delete some of these comments to remove clutter, but then you have a solution right.

Comment: Just include clear instructions for your macos clients to include the header in main.c or equivalent with a proper guard definition e.g. ```#define CMPIMP``` (compile implementation) defined BEFORE the include and then to include the header at leisure everywhere else, of course without the guard.